# How to install wordpress by docker?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

**Question:**

I follow some guides to install the wordpress + mysql by docker, but found that not work... I tried to test by curl command, found no any output, I need your help for the issue...
(I just transfer my wordpress hosting to VPS)

```
docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql
docker run --name wordpress --link mysql:mysql -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=123456 -d wordpress:4.8.2-apache

[root@vps ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6bd3954390e0        wordpress:4.8.2-apache   "docker-entrypoint..."   11 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       80/tcp              wordpress
eaa1f6a2fb96        mysql                    "docker-entrypoint..."   25 seconds ago      Up 24 seconds       3306/tcp            mysql
```

Follow troubleshooting and test wordpress:

```
[root@vps ~]# curl localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:80; Connection refused
[root@vps ~]# docker inspect --format='{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' 6bd3954390e0
172.17.0.3
[root@vps ~]# curl 172.17.0.3:80
[root@vps ~]#
```

**Resolved:**

Thanks @junius([who in docker forums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfwEK.jpg)), @VladoDemcak, @yamenk and @user4860092! The issue was resolved!

If I do “docker run xxxx” that should not work for me, that maybe was caused by command incorrect. Then I tried to do docker-compose, curl no any output, but Wordpress should work normal. **So curl no any output should normal.**

Now, I completed task that transfer my Wordpress to new VPS, share follow tips and experiences:

1. Suggest follow docker [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) if you want to install WP by docker.
2. If you want to mapping the mysql and wordpress, can add follow
   config in compose:

   [image]
3. If you not config port part in compose, that mean not expose any
   port to outside of container, so you couldn't access the port from
   outside, as follow:

   [image]
4. When you change “docker-compose.yml”, please not only use
   “docker-compose down” that will not delete all config/file, suggest
   you do “docker-compose down --volumes” that as install guide.
5. If you change database name, please add “WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: xxx” in
   environment part of Wordpress(docker-compose.yml), that should no
   this config in official install guide. So wordpress default connect
   database name is “wordpress”.
6. If you want to debug wordpress/mysql and check log, you can not add
   “-d”, use this “docker-compose up”
7. In order to restore mysql database, you can install phpmyadmin by
   docker, then add follow config to “docker-compose.yml”, and follow
   guide by “https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/”

   [image]
8. If you want to add some software in docker of Wordpress, e.g: zip,
   mailx, you can do follow:

   [image]

Comment: is the server running on cloud platform..? did you check table routes and ports? also exposing the port is very important.. ie adding -p <outside_port>:80 to the docker run command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have exposed ports, so you are not able to access wordpress (from host) which is running on the `port 80` in docker container.

Probably you will need to expose port to some other port (not 80). So try to change docker run command for wordpress as follows:

```
docker run --name wordpress --link mysql:mysql -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=123456 -p 81:80 -d wordpress:4.8.2-apache
```

Please notice `-p 81:80` parameter in the command - Docker documentation [expose-incoming-ports](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports).

After that wordpress should be available on `localhost:81`.

I would suggest you to create `docker-compose` for your services rather than maintain linking and with `docker-compose` you are also able to run both services with one command.

Comment: Very thanks! But I follow this guide, same phenomenon, how can we verify whether wordpress work normal...  https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

Comment: Thanks VladoDemcak, thanks your notice, yes, I must exposed ports! That work!

Answer (score 1):

There is a very detailed explanation in the official docker docs to how to do this. Follow the link below, and you shall get wordpress up and running.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/